# How to save occurrence data from a search in rgbif

Tags: r, dataframe, save

I am a new R user and I am interested in downloading a particular set of data using rgbif. I did:

```
occ_search(scientificName = "Lupinus", hasCoordinate = TRUE, continent = c('africa', 'europe', 'asia'),
       basisOfRecord = "PRESERVED_SPECIMEN", decimalLatitude = '-1.50750278, 47.62390556',
       decimalLongitude = '-18.75250000, 52.85138889',
       fields = c('scientificName', 'decimalLatitude', 'decimalLongitude', 'country'), return = 'data')
```

Which works fine to do the search. However, what I would like to do is save the search as an object to create an .csv file of it. If I go:

```
OS <- occ_search(scientificName = "Lupinus", hasCoordinate = TRUE, continent = c('africa', 'europe', 'asia'),
       basisOfRecord = "PRESERVED_SPECIMEN", decimalLatitude = '-1.50750278, 47.62390556',
       decimalLongitude = '-18.75250000, 52.85138889',
       fields = c('scientificName', 'decimalLatitude', 'decimalLongitude', 'country'), return = 'data')
```

Then

```
OS1 <- as.data.frame(OS)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(occ) : cannot coerce class ""gbif"" to a data.frame
```

I also tried using `occ_download` this way:

```
OD <- occ_download("scientificName = Lupinus",
                       "hasCoordinate = TRUE",
                       "continent = africa,europe,asia",
                       "basisOfRecord = PRESERVED_SPECIMEN",
                       "decimalLatitude >= -1.50750278", 
                       "decimalLatitude <= 47.62390556",
                       "decimalLongitude >= -18.75250000",
                       "decimalLongitude <= 52.85138889")
```

And all I get is a file with 0 observations and 235 columns.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `occ_search` output is not compatible with `as.data.frame` is in the `continent = c('africa', 'europe', 'asia')` argument. If you look at the `length(OS)` and `str(OS)`, you will see that it actually has three data.frames in it. You can access the individual elements like this:

```
OS$europe
# or
OS['europe']
# or
OS[[1]]
```

You can combine these like this

```
OC1 <- rbind(OS$africa, OS$europe, OS$asia)
```

Or, if you are not going to know all the different names, like this:

```
do.call(rbind, OS)
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform the object with `class "gbif"` to a data.frame you can do `OS.df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, OS)`.

For `occ_download` you need to set a username, email and password. As by gbif website [(http://www.gbif.org/developer/occurrence#download)](http://www.gbif.org/developer/occurrence#download) *Occurrence downloads are created asynchronously - the user requests a download and, once complete, is sent and email with a link to the resulting file.*

`OD <- occ_download(user = "name", pwd = "pass", email = "e@mail.com", "scientificName = Lupinus", "hasCoordinate = TRUE", "continent = africa,europe,asia","basisOfRecord = PRESERVED_SPECIMEN","decimalLatitude >= -1.50750278","decimalLatitude <= 47.62390556","decimalLongitude >= -18.75250000","decimalLongitude <= 52.85138889")`

returns an object of class `gbif download` and you should receive a download link per mail or visit http://www.gbif.org/user/download to download directly. This can be done through the download option at [gbif.org](http://www.gbif.org) as well.

`<<gbif download>> Username: philipprobeck E-mail: phill@gmx.li Download key: 0078579-160910150852091`

Comment: You were faster :) However, actually, you don't need `rbind.data.frame`. Just `rbind` is enough

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) however the download is still an issue. I did specified password, user and email, and I succeeded downloading the .zip folder, but when use `occ_download_get` and `occ_download_import` to get the downloaded data it has no observations and 235 columns.